Why is linear charge density $dq/dl$ and not $q/l$?
If linear charge density is charge per unit length then shouldn't it be $q/l$. Why is it $dq/dl$ instead? Wouldn't that mean it is only being calculated for a small element and not the whole length?

It does not need to be constant over the entire length. Think about the difference between average and instantaneous velocity for an accelerating object.

Because an infinitesimal length $dl$ has an infinitesimal charge $dq$ makes for a finite density:
$$\lambda(l) = \frac{dq}{dl}$$
and the total charge between $0$ and $L$ is:
$$ q = \int_0^L\lambda(l)dl =\int_0^L\frac{dq}{dl} dl$$
and if the charge density is constant, then:
$$\frac{dq}{dl} = \lambda $$
so that:
$$ q = \int_0^L\lambda dl = L\lambda $$
and the charge density is:
$$ \frac{q}{L} = \frac{ L\lambda}{L} = \lambda = \frac{dq}{dl}$$
